# Rename a folder with a variable in the center

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to rename my folder.

Current folder name  = apple. I want to rename it to apsomeple.

The "some" in the centre of the new name will be a variable.

I tried the following but it doesn't work. Please advice. If I add it to the end for testing, it works.

```
name="some"

mv apple ap$nameple # doesn't work
mv apple apple$name # works - just testing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{}` to delimit the name of the variable:

```
mv apple ap${name}ple
```

If there is a chance your variable will contain a space character, unlike the example provided, then in addition you will need to put double quotes around the enter new filename:

```
mv apple "ap${name}ple"
```

Comment: missing double quotes around `ap${name}ple`

Comment: @sjsam Double quotes are not needed.

Comment: Eh.. You sure? consider `name="some stuff"` and test for yourself. They are needed to prevent word splitting in this case.

Comment: Ah ! Much better. :)

Answer (score 3):

Quote your variables!

```
mv apple ap"$name"ple
```

Alternatively, you can use curly braces (still within quotes):

```
mv apple "ap${name}ple"
```

Some may say that the quotes aren't strictly necessary in this case but personally I think that the benefits (a more robust script) outweigh the cost (a measly two extra characters).

Comment: Double quotes are not needed with the braces

Comment: Yeah they are, to prevent word splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: Just tested with `name="ap*"` and `name="so me"`, resulting files were `apap*ple` and `apso meple` regardless of quotes.  I'm using zsh not bash, but I believe they are compatible in this regard.  EDIT: I was wrong!  Double quotes are needed in bash, but not zsh.

Comment: @0x5453 for the first example, I guess that's because you don't have any files that match the pattern `apap*ple`. I'm surprised about the second example; are you sure there's only file?

Comment: @TomFenech See my edit.  I was using zsh, which apparently does not need the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
mv apple "ap${name}ple"
```

should work

---

**Why double quotes are needed in target**

Consider

```
name="some stuff"
```

With

```
mv apple ap${name}ple
```

word splitting happens with `${name}` and you will not get the inteded result.
So `mv` may give you  :

```
mv: target ‘stuffple’ is not a directory
```

With

```
mv apple "ap${name}ple"
```

`ap${name}ple` is considered a single entity.

Comment: Double quotes are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Put braces around the variable name.

```
mv apple "ap${name}ple"
```

EDIT: After some local testing, it looks like zsh and bash handle this case a bit differently.  Bash *does* need the double quotes to prevent word splitting and globbing, while zsh does *not* need the double quotes, and behaves the same way regardless.

Comment: missing double quotes `ap${name}ple`

Comment: @sjsam rather than downvoting everyone's answers, you could actually try doing it yourself and you'd see that the double quotes are not needed.

Comment: @PaulL : That comment seems blunt

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using double quotes so..

```
mv apple ap"$name"ple
```

Comment: Eh! I don't think this deserve a downvote except for the formatting which I have done now !

Answer (score -2):

```
mv /path/tofolder/oldfilename  /path/tofolder/newname
```

eg:
if folder is in located on the Desktop

```
mv /home/Desktop/apple /home/Desktop/apsomeple
```