# Rename a folder with a two or more variable in the new name in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, rename

I am trying to rename the folder via shell script

I have the following variables

folder = windows

os_build = 22621.3008

I want to rename the folder name

windows to new-windows-system-22621.3008

I tried this
mv "$folder" new-${folder}-system-${os_build}

but the file getting renamed as

**new-windows-system-**

Also, I tried mv "$folder" new-"$folder"-system-"$os_build"

Would anyone be able to help me?
I see this link but after trying solutions from link I am not getting answers to that question.
[Rename-folder-with-a-variable-in-the-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224636/rename-a-folder-with-a-variable-in-the-center)

Comment: Please format your question so that we can see the exact commands which you typed. Commands should be in fixed point font, so that we can see spaces inside the commands, and longer commands should be on their own line.

Comment: try this: `mv "$folder" "new-$folder-system-$os_build"` no need for all variables to be in double quotes one after another, if they are used in a string.

Comment: It's hard to tell because of your question's formatting, but `bash` doesn't allow spaces before or after the `=`. Is this present in your script ?

Comment: Although I would quote the whole destination name, it wouldn't be a problem to quote the individual variable references within, instead.  My guess as to the actual problem is that your `os_build` variable is not actually defined or has an empty value.

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find common errors in your shell code (including spaces around `=`).

Answer (score 1):

You should remove spaces before and after the "=".

```
folder=windows
os_build=22621.3008

mv "$folder" new-"$folder"-system-"$os_build"
```